# Angular material menu flickers when hovering

Tags: angular-material, angular8

I'm trying to implement in my project an Angular Menu that displays upon hovering.
I've found [This Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-nested-menu-yclrmd?embed=1&file=app/nested-menu-example.html) that pretty much fits for my needs, the only problem is that when i implement it in my project i'm experiencing a strange  behavior - upon hovering - the menu starts flickering - like showing in the movie... i wonder if anyone has any clue what could have causing it since i could not reproduce it over stackblitz...

[image]